# Globally filter ajax success handlers

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling

I am developing a single page ASP.NET MVC 3 application. All posts are done by [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls. The users can see almost everything on the page but some actions requires the user to login.

If an action requires login, i return a `JSON` `{unauthenticated: true}` if the user is not logged in. So i have several success handlers like:

```
success : function(response){
  if(response.unauthenticated){
    showLoginDialog();
  } else {
    doTheActualWork();
  }
}
```

I want to do it in the global [success](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) handler. Like:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions){
  if(unauthenticated()){
    preventTheLocalSuccess();
    showLoginDialog();
  }
});
```

And the local success handler will be:

```
success: function(response){
  // No Checking
  doTheActualWork();
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What if they just inspect the code and run `doTheActualWork()` manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of returning JSON return the proper HTTP ERROR Code, which in this case would be a `401 Unauthorized`.  Then you can use the `ajaxError` method to handle it.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions){
    switch (xhr.status) {
        case 401: // Unauthorized
             // Take action, referencing xhr.responseText as needed.
            showLoginDialog();
            return false;
            break; 
      }
});
```

Furthermore you can extend your [ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) conditions to handle other failed requests.

Comment: Doesn't work that way. `.ajaxSuccess` will fire its handlers after all the local success handlers have fired. Therefore, you can't prevent from the `.ajaxSuccess`. Further, there is no `preventDefault` in the event object given to the handler.

Comment: Please test your code before answering. Like I said, [the global handlers fire after the local handlers. You can't stop local handlers that way.](http://jsfiddle.net/7366L/1/)

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Please read my code changes.  Since this is now throwing an `Error` condition using `ajaxError` it doesn't have to worry about local handlers.

Comment: If someone could explain why they down voted I'd be happy to fix offending code.

Comment: @Brombomb: Thanks. I will check it later when i will be free.

Comment: @Brombomb A demo was in my comments, check it out.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer  Okay.  Would you like me to remove the `return false`.  In this case yes you can have local and global error functions.  In most cases a local fail isn't necessary, but could be useful.  I've reworded my answer to remove the parts about local and global functions.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the [`dataFilter` property of `$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This property accepts a function which executes just after you receive the request but before any handlers are executed. The main purpose of this is to preprocess data received before they are processed by jQuery itself. Therefore, you will receive the *raw* data. You can do intermediate processes there, like your login.

To patch this configuration to all ajax calls, we use [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to predefine `dataFilter` for all ajax requests. Therefore, each ajax request will have a `dataFilter` handler execute before local handlers execute.

As for sample code, [here's a demo, which pretty much works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/7366L/7/):

```
function login() {
    console.log('login initiated: you are not logged in');
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    dataFilter: function (origdata, type) {

        //the type is determined by the type you indicated in the ajax call
        //if not json, we return the data unharmed
        if (type !== 'json') return origdata;

        //data filter receives the raw response. since we have determined it's json
        //we parse it using jQuery's parseJSON to check the contents
        var data = $.parseJSON(origdata);

        if (data.auth) {
            //if logged in, we just return the data
            return origdata;
        } else {
            //otherwise, we execute the login
            //since returning something is required, we return false so local handler
            //data checks will fail against the false data
            login();
            return false;
        }
    }
});

//the url and data passed is for jsFiddle to work.

//logged in
$.post('/echo/json/', {
    json: JSON.stringify({
        auth: true
    })
}, function (data) {
    //in our handler, it's your normal "check data before use"
    //if data is truthy, it skips this check and moves on
    if(!data) return;
    console.log('data retrieved successfully', data);
}, 'json');

//not logged in
$.post('/echo/json/', {
    json: JSON.stringify({
        auth: false
    })
}, function (data) {
    //since we returned false, the code stops at this check
    if (!data) return;
    console.log('you should not see this since data is false, per dataFilter return', data);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: This method works fine. Just one problem. I have to specify the `dataType` option in my request. Intelligent Guess does not work. Any help on that?

Comment: @Mohayemin It's because `dataFilter` is getting the data *before* jQuery touches the data. jQuery hasn't processed the data to intelligently guess the type.

Comment: Hm, I understand. That means i have to check for another way.

Comment: @Mohayemin I suggest you give the other answer a try.