# Session Start and Action Filter for Session Timeout handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have a MVC4 application with `Windows Authentication`. User can type url of any of the 10 views to load the application. There is no specific home page

I  need to redirect to a session timeout view if the user was idle for more than a minute. I have kept the session timeout value in config file as one minute. And I have created an `action filter` to check one particular session value. This particular session value is set in the `Session_Start` of the `Global.asax`.

But, when the timeout period is over, the request again hits the `Session_Start` and it is assigning the value. Hence my action filter is not redirecting to the error view.
What are the possible solutions to overcome this?

**Web.Config**

```
<system.web>
    <!--Impersonate-->
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
        <!--Session Mode and Timeout-->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" />
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>    
</system.web>
```

**Action Filter**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SessionCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLower();
        HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
        var activeSession = session["IsActiveSession"];
        if (activeSession == null)
        {
            //Redirect
            var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            var loginUrl = url.Content("~/Error/SessionTimeout");
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Global.ASAX**

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["IsActiveSession"] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259230/globally-filter-ajax-success-handlers  and [408 Error Code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 11):

Instead of setting a session value and checking it in your action filter, simply check `HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession` to see if a new session was created for the current request. Modifying your action filter, you would end up with something like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SessionCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLower();
        HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
        if (session.IsNewSession)
        {
            //Redirect
            var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            var loginUrl = url.Content("~/Error/SessionTimeout");
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
        }

    }
}
```

if you want to get fancy and make sure they had a previous session before the new session that was created for this request, you can update the `if` statement to check if an old session cookie was sent with the request:

```
string cookieHeader = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
if (session.IsNewSession && cookieHeader != null && cookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)
{
    ...
}
```

But since it looks like you are sending them to a login page, this is probably not something you have to worry about here. If you do use this check, note that this code assumes the default `"ASP.NET_SessionId"` cookie name; this could be changed in your web.config, in which case you would need to either update the `IndexOf` parameter with the new cookie name or [get the cookie name programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739537/how-to-programmatically-get-session-cookie-name).

Comment: Blog post link is broken.

Comment: Thanks, I have replaced it.

Comment: The link for explaining how to check for an old session was not ideal, so I have just moved the explanation inline.